# How can I calculate the velocity of the centre of mass of a 3 body system and substract it from the initial conditions in python

Tags: python, arrays, simulation

I am writing a Python program to simulate a 3 body system. The simulation works fine. Now I wanted to calculate the velocity of the center of mass and subtract it from the initial conditions so that the observer moves in the center of gravity system. But when I try my method, nothing happens. The plot looks exactly the same as without subtracting the velocity of the center of mass.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = 6.67428e-11

def Gravitation3D(m1, x1, m2, x2, m3, x3):
    r12 = x2-x1
    r21 = x1-x2
    r13 = x3-x1
    r31 = x1-x3
    r23 = x3-x2
    r32 = x2-x3
    rabs12 = la.norm(r12)
    rabs21 = la.norm(r21)
    rabs13 = la.norm(r13)
    rabs31 = la.norm(r31)
    rabs23 = la.norm(r23)
    rabs32 = la.norm(r32)
    F12 = -G * m1 * m2 / rabs12**2 * r12/rabs12
    F21 = G * m1 * m2 / rabs21**2 * r21/rabs21
    F13 = -G * m3 * m1 / rabs13**2 * r13/rabs13
    F31 = G * m3 * m1 / rabs31**2 * r31/rabs31
    F23 = -G * m3 * m2 / rabs23**2 * r23/rabs23
    F32 = G * m3 * m2 / rabs32**2 * r32/rabs32
    return F12, F21, F13, F31, F23, F32

def Simulation7(m1, x10, v10, m2, x20, v20, m3, x30, v30, n, dt):
    x1 = []; x2 = []; x3 = []
    v1 = []; v2 = []; v3 = []
    a1 = []; a2 = []; a3 = []
    t = []
    x1.append(x10); x2.append(x20); x3.append(x30)
    v1.append(v10); v2.append(v20); v3.append(v30)
    t.append(0)
    F12, F21, F13, F31, F23, F32 = Gravitation3D(m1, x10, m2, x20, m3, x30)
    a1.append((F12+F13) / m1); a2.append((F21+F23) / m2); a3.append((F31 + F32) / m3)

    for i in range(n):
        F12, F21, F13, F31, F23, F32 = Gravitation3D(m1, x1[-1], m2, x2[-1], m3, x3[-1])
        a1.append((F12+F13) / m1); a2.append((F21+F23) / m2); a3.append((F31 + F32) / m3)
        v1.append(v1[-1] + a1[-2] * dt); v2.append(v2[-1] + a2[-2] * dt); v3.append(v3[-1] + a3[-2] * dt)
        x1.append(x1[-1] + v1[-1] * dt); x2.append(x2[-1] + v2[-1] * dt); x3.append(x3[-1] + v3[-1] * dt)
        t.append(t[-1] + dt)

    return np.array(x1), np.array(v1), np.array(a1), np.array(x2), np.array(v2), np.array(a2), np.array(x3), np.array(v3), np.array(a3), np.array(t)
m1 = 1.9891e30
p1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
v1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
m2 = 1898.8e24
p2 = np.array([778.5e9, 0, 0])
v2 = np.array([0, 13060, 0])
m3 = 5.97e20
p3 = np.array([3.8925e11, 6.74201e11, 0])
v3 = np.array([-11310.66720747398, 6530.216756949375, 0])

#Calculation of the velocity of the center of mass

vs = (m1 * v1 + m2 * v2 + m3 * v3) / (m1 + m2 + m3)

v1 = v1 - vs
v2 = v2 - vs
v3 = v3 - vs

simp1, simv1, sima1, simp2, simv2, sima2, simp3, simv3, sima3, t =  Simulation7(m1, p1, v1, m2, p2, v2, m3, p3, v3, 500000, 10000)
```

I thought that I could calculate vs simply with this formula because the the initial conditions are stored as arrays. But it does not work.

Comment: Can you share what happens inside Simulation? It is worth noting that only the second entry of vs has significant value.

Comment: I've added the simulation code